# Use variable to determine background image url

Tags: jquery, css

```
$(".Go_Image").live('click', function(event) {
    var imageurl = $("#ImageUrl").attr('value');

    $('#Image').css({'background-image', 'url(' + imageurl + ')'});

});
```

Syntax correction; the user types/pastes a link to an image in an input field. Once he hits go, the background image for the element #Image changes to that link, otherwise known as the value for the input element.

*EDIT*

This script, as is, does not work. Not sure why.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking here...

Comment: Where is it failing? Couldn't you just use `$('#ImageUrl').val()`?

Comment: Oh sorry, the problem is that the background-image source replacement does not work, not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#image').css({'background-image', 'url(' + imageurl + ')'});`

don't forget to add `repeat: no-repeat;` if you need it and specify dimensions.

Comment: You don't need to escape double quotes inside a single quoted string.